# What is the name for a computer case that exposes the motherboard when opening?

Tags: case, case-mods

I'm looking for a PC case that is *functioning* like old Macintosh cases.

This is the case of a Power Macintosh G3 B&W.  Notice it has a hinged door that opens downwards and has the motherboard on the case door.

[image: mac case]

I don't need a case that "looks like" a Mac, but want a case that, when opening its side panel, exposes the motherboard, with the memory, CPU and all cards mounted on it. That makes them more easily accessible.

Inside the "fixed part" of the case, there are HDD, CD, power supply and so on.

Do such cases exist for PCs in ATX format? If so, what are they called, so I can look for them online?

I found a zillion "Mac-like cases" which "look like" a Mac – but the board is screwed inside like in standard PC cases.

Comment: Some of the older Dell Optiplex models have a similar design. The Small Form Factor GX280's have it for example.

Comment: @Davidw No they do not. I have opened a GX280 and they absolutely do not. They have the motherboard within the case when the case opens. This has the motherboard on the 'door' of the case as you should see from his picture. Furthermore this thing does the whole thing standing upright. The GX280 is here http://i986.photobucket.com/albums/ae343/Parliament10/Desktops/GX280Tower-Open.jpg

Comment: I don't think such cases are practical. You'll have problems with wires being haphazardly squeezed against components when closing or pulled when opening. It looks like Apple made special cabling arrangements to mitigate this problem, yet I don't believe they continued to use this design in later Macs.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's called a "clamshell". Some old Dell computers used the same case design, such as the Dell Dimension 8200.

Comment: @joeqwerty No the Dell Dimension 8200 does not have the design in the pic. here is a pic of it http://www.danzfamily.com/archives/blogphotos/328computeropen.jpg   See  my comment about the Dell GX280(that somebody else suggested.Both Dells look like the same design. That's not the design of the MAC in the pic. My comment actually spells out the significant differences between that design and the one of the MAC in the pic. But look at it and see the significant differences.

Comment: @barlop - I see what you mean as for the placement of the components but I would argue that the actual case is a "clamshell" in both instances. What would you call it?

Comment: @joeqwerty i'd describe it(hinged door that opens downwards with the motherboard on the case door), and i'd refer to it more concisely as the Powerbook G3 B&W design,but it looks like it has never been repeated on any case since,and it looks like there isnt a name for it unfortunately.but there shuld b as the design clearly has some huge merits. It may have been a bit cramped..n apple apparently put the wires under the mbrd(for prettyness and maybe space).But that's not a reason for them not to repeat the hinged door opening downwards with mbrd on door.one could be done with more space.

Comment: Hey folks, grab yourselves a chat for discussion please. Post an answer if you have a suggestion for what the name is.

Comment: Nah, chat is too closed for my liking, and all those Twitter followers will miss earlier dicussions...? (And we can always clean up later.) I'm with @joeqwerty here, that many layouts might be called a clamshell. Like from a review of some Lenovo machine: [*"The chassis opens like a clamshell, with the drives in one half and the motherboard in the other half"*](http://www.computershopper.com/desktops/reviews/lenovo-thinkcentre-m91p-0266-b8u-ultrasmall-desktop). Not sure if there would be a more specific name for the motherboard being on the moving part though (and if the OP needs that).

Comment: Notice I did not say it was exactly like the Mac...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a name for those features - hinge door opening downwards with motherboard on the door.  But while there isn't a particular name, you can look up particular terms to find such a design.

It didn't exist prior to the case you pictured, the Powermac G3 B&W (Note, the Powermac G3 pre B&W did not have such a case).

From wikipedia on the G3 B&W,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Macintosh_G3_(Blue_%26_White)

> Though still based on the PowerPC G3 architecture, the G3 B&W was a
>   totally new design. The first new Power Mac model after the release of
>   the iMac, it used a novel enclosure with the logic board on the
>   folding "door", which swung down onto the desk for easy access (a
>   design that was also used on all Power Mac G4 models except for the
>   Cube)

So, it was repeated with the Powermac G4,

There have been people modding the case(the modders say it has to be an mATX(Micro ATX) case.  And there has even been a PC case based on that design.

So if you look up PC case like Powermac G4, this page comes up, the Nikao Submarine,  unfortunately that was in the  year 2000-2002.    mentioned [here](http://www.theapplecollection.com/design/pcreleased/NikaoSubmarine.html)  and [archive.org has page of nikao submarine on the nikao site here](https://web.archive.org/web/20020210113628/http://www.nikao.net/case/submarine.htm)   It was manufactured in south korea, and was an ATX case.

[image]
[image]

Nikao doesn't seem to be up anymore. Scrolling down to the bottom of the Nicao site it  says "Tradex Information Technology Inc" but they don't seem to be around either.

Googling i've done hasn't picked up anything since, other than people modding or trying to get one.

There is the Dell optiplex GX280 case some have mentioned, that has some merits, but not like that G3 B&W / G4 case.  The GX280 opens like a shark mouth minus the teeth i.e. it has to be pryed open(or let the weight of the case pry it open as you push the buttons on the side and lift the 'door' up a bit). Not like a thin door. And the door doesn't open downwards with the case upwards, you have to turn it on its side and the door opens upwards. And the motherboard is not on the door of the case. It's screwed into the base.  But it has its merits, it's a good design, relatively speaking it's very convenient to operate on.    But you'll have issues modding that case. A google shows the power supply is a very funny/non-standard shape. So, knowing of that case isn't that helpful. It has variations but GX280s I see seem to be small sized too.
[image]

if you were to mod a case you'd be better off modding the mac G3 B&W or G4 one, which is what some people have done, and is the case you want. Though even the Mac one is mATX rather than ATX so smaller than ATX, less room on the board for cards. But at least that's still a standard, which is preferable to the Dell.

I see many links of people modding the G4 case, articles dated 2009, even 2012. Though the computer was sold 1999-2004. It is clearly a much loved case design. And the best 'name' for it, for googling it, is the Powermac G4 case.  or the model that brought it into being(which you pictured), the Powermac G3 B&W.

**Added**
Incorporating some comments.
The OP found the Sigma Unicorn case,

It is an ATX.  case pictured below, from this [hardwaresecrets review](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/printpage/Sigma-Unicorn-Case-Review/566). You see it open with motherboard showing on the open door that (as described in [this tomshardware review](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/pc-case-roundup,1951-2.html))  hinges downwards.

[image: link]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm surprised with two things: How hard is search for something what hasn't an exact name ;), and why the PC industry didn't picked such design - IMO it is really very good design. /Maybe Apple has an patent on it.. ;(/ And the idea convert the old G3/G4 case to PC case is a nice option. ;)

Comment: @jm666 oh it's not hard to search.. powermac g4 is pretty well known and the design was noticed and has people talking about it and asking after it for years,and modding it.It's common for good design computer cases to not be repeated!I've seen it happen with a chieftec(got one 10 years ago,went back some years later,the shop said the cases weren't as good now).Note that you say G3..only the G3 B&W.I added a quote from wikipedia that makes that point more explicit.In future people will be printing computer cases with their 3d printers.And distant future maybe even scan in a G3 B&W / G4 case

Comment: Found another _pure PC_ case searched as `"hinged door" "pc case"` Sigma Unicorn case [reviewed here.](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/pc-case-roundup,1951-2.html)

Comment: @jm666 great find,there is a review on one page here http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/printpage/Sigma-Unicorn-Case-Review/566  and there is a pic of it open with motherboard showing here  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=21cxbbb&s=5#.U7klEvldWqI  and it is ATX according to that review.The manufacturer should really have used a pic like that and made it a selling point.That was 2008 and out of stock on newegg and I don't see any cases on the manufacturer site.But may be available here http://www.eio.com/p-29226-raidmax-unicorn-st-sigma-unicorn-black-10-steel-secc-atx-mid-tower-computer-case.aspx

Comment: @jm666  Looking on google images, a lot of hinged door examples hinge sideways and don't expose the motherboard.   Rather than downward and exposing the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

The Raidmax Smilodon line of cases can do this.  For some reason pictures of them with the panel folded down and the mobo installed are impossible to find, but here is are pics of one empty:

[image: a Smilodon case]

[image: another Smilodon case]

The term I see used is "foldout motherboard tray".

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a clamshell case. As a few people have stated, older Dell OptiPlex's used a similar case. I tried finding new ones for sale and wasn't able to.

The issue with attempting to use say an older OptiPlex is the case is proprietary. For the most part only their power supply will fit and it won't be one you'd want to use.

Comment: I suggest  you try including a pic, and try stating the significant similarities and differences. such as the fact that while the case is hinged, it doesn't open downwards, and it doesn't have the motherboard on the door of the case. (also it's not hinged like a door, more like something pryed apart like a shark mouth minus teeth, but did seem more convenient than most, but not as convenient looking as the one posted by the OP.